# ‘RColourBrewer’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap using gplots, but can't install RColourBrewer.

I think I'm using the latest version of R. Do I have to uninstall it and reinstall an older version of R that is compatible with RColourBrewer?

> install.packages("RColourBrewer")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Melissa/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘RColourBrewer’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Warning message:
package ‘RColourBrewer’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1) 
>

Comment: See this answer to troubleshoot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/1927583

Comment: It is spelled `RColorBrewer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RColorBrewer` not `RColourBrewer`